# finding the expression in the file, processing the content until the next occurrence of the expression in loop in UNIX

Tags: loops, unix

Input file is:

```
ABC 
line1
line2
line3
ABC
line3
line2
ABC
line1
```

Here I want to use the loop in unix and process each part once I get the word ABC until the next occurrence of ABC

Comment: Does your file has a single line or there are multiple lines ? Also can ABC occur multiple times in a line ?

Comment: there are multiple lines, and ABC too occur multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear, but here is something that could help, a bash script:

```
export flag=0; cat txt.txt |while read oneline; do 
  echo $oneline; 
  if [ "$oneline" = "ABC" ]; then 
    echo "Trig, flag=$flag"; 
    let flag=(1-$flag); 
  else 
    echo "process: $oneline"; 
  fi; 
done
```

The ouput is:

```
ABC
Trig, flag=0
line1
process: line1
line2
process: line2
line3
process: line3
ABC
Trig, flag=1
line3
process: line3
line2
process: line2
ABC
Trig, flag=0
line1
process: line1
```

Of course, not knowing what do you mean by "process" the lines, I simply used a flag to remember the state and an "echo $oneline" to simulate the process.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like below .

Here the required data is available in the temp file in each loop iteration . Process it accordingly you want it .

File name is : test.txt

```
line_array=$(grep -nw ABC test.txt | awk -F":" '{print $1 }')

for range in `awk '{ a[++i]=$0;} END { for (key in a) {print a[key]","a[key+1];}}' <<< "$line_array"`; do echo "BLOCK START" ; range_start=`awk -F"," '{ print $1}' <<< "$range"`; range_start=$(( $range_start + 1 )); range_end=`awk -F"," '{ print $2}' <<< "$range"`;  if [ ! -z ${range_end} ] ;then range_end=$(( $range_end - 1 ))  ;fi ;range=$range_start","$range_end ; range=$(sed 's/,$/,\$/g' <<< "$range") ;  sed -n "${range}p" test.txt > temp; cat temp; echo "BLOCK END" ;done
```

Output :

```
BLOCK START
line1
line2
line3
BLOCK END
BLOCK START
line3
line2
BLOCK END
BLOCK START
line1
BLOCK END
```

Answer (score 0):

good answer by Mathews Jose!!
i have another alternative if you'd like,

i used your content as a "dummyfile", you can use your actual file name here.

```
for value in $(cat dummyfile |perl -p -e 's/\n/,/' | sed -e 's/ //g' -e 's/ABC,/ /g' -e 's/, / /g' -e 's/,$//g')
do
     echo "EXECUTION START"
     for innerloop in $(echo ${value} | sed 's/,/ /g')
     do
              # DO YOUR CALCULATIONS HERE
              echo $innerloop
     done
     echo "EXECUTION STOP"
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
EXECUTION START
line1
line2
line3
EXECUTION STOP
EXECUTION START
line3
line2
EXECUTION STOP
EXECUTION START
line1
EXECUTION STOP
```